# Matplotlib contour with blank areas

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I have a set of data that comprises x and y coordinates and a calculated value for each coordinate. The grid is irregular so for now i have been creating a scatter plot and separating the values into bins to display as a contour as on the img at the link below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7XHm.png

I want to refine this method by using the imshow/contour functionality in matplotlib by using meshgrid and then interpolating the calculated values. I can get this to work fine but I end up with a problem that it loses the areas of the image with no data (voids in real life) and joins them up as shown on the image at the link below for the same data.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCRog.png

I've tried to find the best way to do this but I haven't found any help on this. Does anyone have suggestions?

I think I need to amend the method at the meshgrid stage but I'm not sure about this. For what its worth my code is below

```
    x=nodalData[:,1] #array of x values from input file
    y=nodalData[:,2] #array of y values from input file

    #define the linear grid
    xi, yi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100), np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 100) 
    xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

    z=Rres #array calculated elsewhere corresponding to x,y pair

    #interpolate
    zi = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), z, (xi, yi), method='cubic')
    #plot    
    plt.imshow(zi, vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max(), origin='lower', extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
```

Comment: You want to **mask** some regions, right?
check this [example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html)...

Comment: The problem is that the position of the masked regions changes depending on the inputs. Ideally, I'd like the grid of points which is contoured to not include the data voids in the first place if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Its a strange problem, as the point of interpolation is to find reasonable estimates for regions where there is insufficient data. I would suggest either accepting that the new plot has interpolated values, and so its ok if the 'no data' regions are no longer present. Or, you could put the `data voids` back in after doing your interpolation, by using your first plot as a mask for example.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is a better visualisation of the data which I think is achieved by the contour plot. The data represents the floor slabs of buildings and so there are some areas which do not have a slab in place - interpolating into these areas is misleading. From what I know of masking this would be difficult for void areas that are different in each situation so I was hoping not to rely on masking after the interpolation. Instead I wondered if it was possible to add voids into the original mesh?

Comment: @LCSA - Looks like you can avoid interpolating into those regions, by excluding them from your `xi, yi` data points (ie. exclude them, do the interpolation, put the original points back). Also, I think the link posted in your comments above, may allow you to mask before the interpolation, which may be a different way of doing it (although I have found scipy to not respect numpy masks in the past, so I am not certain).